# How to import BeanPostProcessor for KafkaBinderConfigurationProperties to kafka's binder application context

Tags: spring-cloud-stream, spring-cloud-stream-binder-kafka

I am having a request which needs to implement a **BeanPostProcessor** for **KafkaBinderConfigurationProperties**. While if I define this **BeanPostProcessor** as a static bean in my configuration class, I can see my BPP being loaded only to the application's application context instead of the kafka binder's context, so the BPP cannot take effects. Here my application uses only a single kafka binder.

The way I currently find to make it loaded to the binder's context is to add my configuration class for my BPP as the binder's sources through the property of [spring.main.sources](https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-stream/docs/current/reference/html/spring-cloud-stream.html#multiple-systems). But I am wondering is there any other solutions to make my BPP (or my configuration class for BPP) loaded to the binder's context without setting the configuration sources for the single binder case?

Comment: I think we need to look into this. Can you create an issue in Spring Cloud Stream repository for this? Please add some more context and link to this issue. If you can provide some code samples for what you are doing, that would certainly be helpful.

Comment: thanks @sobychacko, issue created https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-stream/issues/2446